# How to take indices and name of a variable in Sage?

Tags: sagemath

I define the following in Sage.

```
rank=8
R=PolynomialRing(QQ, 'a' ,rank+1)
a=R.gens()
```

I would like to define a function f which returns the index of a[3]: f(a[3])=3 and define another function g such that g(a[3])=a. How to do this in Sage? Thank you very much!

Comment: This question is likely out of scope on math stack exchange; such questions are welcome on [Ask Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer draws on the one by Alex J Best for defining `f`,
but also defines `g`.

Define a multivariate polynomial ring and its generator tuple:

```
sage: R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'a', 4)
sage: R
Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a0, a1, a2, a3 over Rational Field
sage: a = R.gens()
sage: a
(a0, a1, a2, a3)
```

Consider one of the generators (or "indeterminates", or "variables"):

```
sage: p = a[2]
sage: p
a2
```

To get its index in the generator tuple:

```
sage: a.index(p)
2
```

This can be made into the function `f` requested in the question:

```
sage: f = a.index
sage: f(p)
2
```

The above is tied to the definition of `a`; more generally:

```
def f(p):
    r"""
    Return the index of this generator of a polynomial ring.
    """
    return p.parent().gens().index()
```

What function `g` the question requests is not entirely clear.

If we want `g(a[2])` to return the string `'a'`:

```
def g(p):
    r"""
    Return the generator name stripped of its index.
    """
    return ''.join(c for c in str(p) if not c.isdigit())
```

With that definition:

```
sage: p = a[2]
sage: aa, k = g(p), f(p)
sage: aa
'a'
sage: k
2
sage: ak = aa + str(k)
sage: ak
'a2'
sage: ak == str(p)
True
sage: R(ak) == p
True
```

If instead we want `g(a[2])` to return the tuple `R.gens()`:

```
def g(p):
    r"""
    Return the tuple of generators of the parent polynomial ring.
    """
    return p.parent().gens()
```

With that definition:

```
sage: p = a[2]
sage: aa, k = g(p), f(p)
sage: aa
(a0, a1, a2, a3)
sage: k
2
sage: ak = aa[k]
sage: ak
a2
sage: ak == p
True
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something generic about lists in python so

```
a.index(a[3])
```

for the first (you can write `f = a.index` if you like), and for the second if you really want a function rather than using `[3]` you can do

```
def g(n):
    return a[n]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! a.index(a[3]) works! But the other function I would like to define is to take the name of the variable. For example, g(b[3])=b. In maple, we can use indets(b[3]). Do you know how to do this in Sage? Thank you very much!